# is it possible to view php information when scraping a site's html using python?

Tags: python, php, html

Would it be possible to retrieve the information using python from the php here within the src tag? Thank you.

---

```html
<iframe frameborder="0" height="22" id="MLVALUEDFT_bandgap_HF" scrolling="no" src="ML_print_value.php?p=DFT_bandgap_HF&amp;f=321227475&amp;u=eV&amp;sd=1&amp;mod=_aTbTme" width="100%">
```

Answer (score 0):

should not be possible，[about this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_intro.asp)
PHP is a server scripting language. When you access it, it will be loaded directly on the server and will not be passed to the user.